# Translating Java code into JSTL (or EL)

Tags: java, jstl, el

As java hard coding is now forbidden in my company's `jsp` pages, I'm trying to translate the following two lines in `JSTL`:

```
<% out.clear();
out = pageContext.pushBody(); %>
```

The purpose is to avoid the (infamous) exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

I tried to write some `<c:set var='out' value='out.clear()'/>` for example but nothing works.

How can I write those two lines into JSTL (or EL) ?

Comment: Maybe http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm can help you.

Comment: Thanks. In which way this could help me clearing the JspWriter ?